# Open a new JQuery Dialog when close one through dialog close event

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I try to open a new dialog when click the "upload" button of "delimitedFileDialog" dialog, since when I click "upload" the "delimitedFileDialog" dialog closes automatically, so I want to take advantage of close event to open a new one, is it feasible? I am new to JQuery, please give me some hints. How can I open a new dialog when "upload" is hit?

```
             <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    var uploadDialog, previewDialog;
                    uploadDialog = $("#delimitedFileDialog").dialog({
                        autoOpen: false,
                        appendTo: "form",
                        height: "auto",
                        width: "auto",
                        modal: true,
                        close: function (event, ui) {
                            previewDialog = $("#bomListPreviewDialog").dialog({
                                autoOpen: false,
                                appendTo: "form",
                                height: "auto",
                                width: "auto",
                                modal: true,
                            });

                            previewDialog.dialog("open");
                        },
                    });

                    $("#newDelimited").button().on("click", function () {
                        uploadDialog.dialog("open");
                    });


                });
            </script>
```

The following is the code for "delimitedFileDialog".

```
                <div class="dialogueModal" id="delimitedFileDialog" title="New from delimited file">
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="delimitedFileUpload" runat="server" />
                    <br /><br /> 
                    <div align="center">
                        <asp:Button ID="uploadBtn" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="btnNewDelimited_Click"/>
                    </div>              
            </div>
```

I put break point in btnNewDelimited_Click method, which works well to generate parsed data and bind them to the "delimitedPreview" GridView, but this dialog does not show up.

```
<div class="dialogueModal" id="bomListPreviewDialog" title = "BOM Preview">
                <asp:GridView ID="delimitedPreview" DataKeyNames="PartNumber" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
              ...Columns DEF...To save space....
                </asp:GridView>
```

Anyone can help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move the code responsible for creating second dialog (#bomListPreviewDialog) outside the event, to create dialog when the page loads, and then in the event `close` of first dialog open the second dialog `previewDialog.dialog("open");`

http://jsfiddle.net/5v74phd4/1/

JS:

```
var uploadDialog, previewDialog;

previewDialog = $("#bomListPreviewDialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    appendTo: "form",
    height: "auto",
    width: "auto",
    modal: true
});

uploadDialog = $("#delimitedFileDialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    appendTo: "body",
    height: "auto",
    width: "auto",
    modal: true,
    close: function (event, ui) {
        //previewDialog.dialog("open");
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

http://jsfiddle.net/5v74phd4/3/

```
$('#uploadBtn').click(function() {
    uploadDialog.dialog("open");
});
```

Comment: Your answer is helpful, but I am sorry that my original post was misunderstanding. Just made changes to it.